# Why does dotnet run launch 2 processes?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

When I run my dotnet core 2 app from my PowerShell I always see 2 processes launched.
This is annoying as in Visual Studio 2017 I cannot "reattach" a debugger as there are always 2 processes with the same name "dotnet".

[image]

Any way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dotnet run` is a development command that builds the project and queries the project for the actual command to run. It then launches the program described in the program - which may be a `dotnet some.dll` or `someapp.exe` depending on the program type.

To work around your issue, run a command like

```
dotnet bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\mapp.dll
```

directly to avoid process noise.

You can also chain a build command before it so you can rebuild the project on changes and still have the process that runs msbuild terminate:

```
dotnet build; dotnet bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\mapp.dll
```

Comment: YES this works, thanks a lot. 
the workaround is a bit cumbersome. too bad there is no easier way.
even a different process name would be enough.
Just 2 times "dotnet" ...